# CSS animation bug on Safari

Tags: ios, css

I have a CSS animation bug on Safari where the wave animation I created does not behave as expected.

below is my animation keyframe:

```
@keyframes wave {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-18px);
  }
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
}
```

I created a pen for it - https://codepen.io/ikhazen/pen/BXdqrN
it behaves as expected in other browsers but not on Safari iPhone 6s.

To explain what was happening on my iPhone.
The first three dots animate at once, followed by the 4th and 5th dots. it seems like the animation-delay property isn't working very well. 
and sometimes, I noticed that all dots animate at once. which is weird.

Thanks

Comment: I checked on iPhone 7 and it works fine. Maybe you don't have all updates installed on your iPhone?

Comment: @somega thanks, yeah it works fine on my phone sometimes but usually, it behaves differently which is really weird.

Comment: On Safari on Mac, the first dot goes first, then all the rest go together.

Comment: @MarkFisher thanks!.
what do you think could be the problem? is it really a bug on Safari browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumble upon this, try using a negative value in your animation-delay property.

here's the link https://codepen.io/ikhazen/pen/BXdqrN

```
&-6 {
  background: #c73e2c;
  animation-delay: -150ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -150ms;
}

&-5 {
  background: #ac3c3f;
  animation-delay: -300ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -300ms;
}

&-4 {
  background: #903a51;
  animation-delay: -450ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -450ms;
}

&-3 {
  background: #733866;
  animation-delay: -600ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -600ms;
}

&-2 {
  background: #573678;
  animation-delay: -750ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -750ms;
}

&-1 {
  background: #3c348a;
  animation-delay: -900ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -900ms;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just had this same problem on hover states in Safari with links and icon font in pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`. The fix was to make the delay -0.1s for each attribute. Positive values didn't work. This worked using the `transition` shorthand and without the webkit prefix and the animation still appears to work fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a similar problem on Safari on Mac OS, except the first dot goes on it's own, followed by the rest together. I have created a working pen [here](https://codepen.io/markfisher/pen/rXzPNj).

The problem is with the following css in your pen

```
@-webkit-keyframes wave {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-18px);
  }
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
}
```

Changing it so that the percentages are in order fixes it:

```
@-webkit-keyframes wave {
  0% {
    transform initial;
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-18px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: initial;
  }
  100% {
    transform: initial;
  }
}
```

If I am interpreting the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/#keyframes) correctly when it says

> To determine the set of keyframes, all of the values in the selectors are sorted in increasing order by time

then this would seem to a bug in Safari, as the order in which you specifiy the keyframes should not matter.

Comment: @thanks, but it still didn't work.
I really think that this is a Safari bug.

see your pen screenshot here.
https://imgur.com/a/cmREdz6

Comment: @Hitori, You are right, I have just tested on ios 11 on an iPhone 6s using browserstack. Interestingly the behaviour can differ on each page refresh. Sometimes the 2nd and 3rd are nearly synchronised but the other dots are OK. Sometimes all the dots are synchronised. Sometimes I get what you described. For what it's worth, your original pen works consistently in iOS12 and even in the older ios9 on 6s, even thought codepen itself isn't fully supported. But behaviour seems incosistent on ios11 - I guess that is that what you're using?

Comment: @Hitori, Also I have realised that your pen sometimes works and sometimes fails on desktop mac, and my solution didn't actually seem to change that - it just happened to work on the first try.

Comment: thanks. it looks like using a negative value for the animation-delay did the trick for me.
here's the updated pen - https://codepen.io/ikhazen/pen/BXdqrN

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
&-1 {
  background: #3c348a;
  animation-delay: 150ms;
}
```

is missing -webkit-animation-delay: 150ms;

Working code:

```
&-1 {
  background: #3c348a;
  animation-delay: 150ms;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 150ms;
}
```

Advice: use css autoprefixer to avoid such errors.

Comment: actually no. since I'm using webpack. it should auto-prefix those CSS rules.

Comment: If you are using the script create-react-app, the the autoprefix should worked out of the box. If you are building your app with webpack, you should set it up by yourself.

Comment: I am using Vue and laravel-mix setup, and I confirm that the compiled CSS file has vendor prefixes.